# mysql update using for each loop from post array

Tags: php, arrays, post

sorry for my confusing question.
let me rephrase the details:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

sample data:

Item Name:     Quantity:
Coke           2
Pepsi          3
Gatorade       4     


<form action="exec.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php for each loop goes here?/>"
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php for each loop goes here?/>"
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now, in my exec.php page.

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$item_code =$_POST['item_code'];
 $quantity =$_POST['quantity'];

$test= explode('\n',$item_code); 
$test2 = explode('\t',$quantity);

this part is where my problem is..
here is my update query:

foreach($item as $test){ 
$update = "UPDATE table SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE item_code='$item_code'" 
}
}

as you can see, $quantity will be left out, since it would also need to be looped to match the $item_code.

or is there any better way to do this?

im quite new to php, so please pardon me if im doing it wrong the way..

Comment: It is quite unclear what your intent is here. Please post your PHP code.  I suspect you ought to be creating inputs as arrays like `<input type='hidden' name='item_name[]' />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand, do you have an issue reading the data from `MySQL`? do you have an issue updating the data to `MySQL`? In any case it seems that you are refering a `SQL` issue rather than an `HTML` or `PHP`, can you post your `SQL` script?